# Databricks vs bigquery pricing

Tags: google-bigquery, databricks

If I run exact same query with exam same data on Databricks vs Bigquery - what would be the cost difference between two?
I read many articles but no one has been specific in this case so far.

Lets assume I have accounts table with 2 TB of logical storage. I want to count total active accounts. Its partitioned on active_inactive flag column.

How much will it cost to find total active accounts in BQ vs Databricks ?

We should include storage cost for both BQ as well as databricks.

Comment: Hi @Aseem, Can you refer to these [document1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage-api) , [document2](https://docs.gcp.databricks.com/administration-guide/account-settings/usage.html#usage-details) and [document3](https://www.databricks.com/product/pricing/databricks-sql) , hopefully it will help you.